# Book on Repeated Measure Analysis

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures, references, random-effects-model

Can anyone recommend a good book or some other reading materials 
on repeated measure analysis using mixed model.

Comment: Hi Hanna, my suggestion is Applied Longitudinal Analysis by Garrett Fitzmaurice, Nan Laird & James Ware http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala/ - it's a good introductory book with tons of worked examples.

Comment: +1 on that. Very good book in general but I would argue that the mixed modelling part of it isn't that amazing. Linear Mixed Models: A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software by West et al. http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bwest/almmussp.html is better as first read as the Mixed Model comes first and then the longitudinal data follow.

Comment: There are a lot of books out there that talk about repeated measure analysis using mixed models. It would be helpful if you could be more specific about what kind of book you'd prefer so that we could narrow down the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend

Models for Repeated Measurements (Second Edition). JK Lindsey. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1999, ISBN: 0-19-850599-0.
https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/31/3/701/629802

Also, Dimitris Rizopoulos, who is active on here has an excellent course:
https://www.nihes.com/course/ce08_repeated_measurements/
and the slides from it are available online:
https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf